# When get the real width?

Tags: android

I have set programmaticaly the width of a button to 0dp and a weight of 1 so that it has the same width of the rest of the buttons of the gridview.

The problem is that i cannot succeed in setting the height equals to the width as the width has been set to 0.

So i would like to know when the button takes its real width. For now, i'm using viewTreeObserver but i only get the good width when I click on the button.

Do you have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom view subclass and override onMeasure.  In your onMeasure, look at the measurespec to find out how big you can be, and set your appropriate width and height.

onMeasure is the function your parent view calls to figure out the size of its subviews.  Make sure to call setMeasuredDimension inside onMeasure, or you'll throw an exception somewhere.

Comment: thank you a lot it works ! There is just the text on the button which lost its position, now it's at the top right corner but i guess i will find out.

Comment: It's ok i had to set a gravity center !